# How to append new table rows on top of selected row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append table row on top of selected row. Here is what I tried

```js
function maintest() {

  let table;
  let row0;
  let row1;
  let cell0;
  let cell1;
  let input2;
  let button; 
  
  table = $('<table>');
  table.attr({
    "id": "testTable"
  });


  row0 = $('<tr>').attr({"id":"selectedRow"});
  table.append(row0);
  cell0 = $('<td>');
  row0.append(cell0);
  input2 = $("<input>").attr({"class":"input0"});
  cell0.append(input2);

  cell1 = $('<td>');
  row0.append(cell1);
  
  button = $("<button>").attr({"class":"btn"}).text("Button").click(function() {
      row1 = $('<tr>').insertBefore($("#selectedRow"));
      table.append(row1);
      let cell2 = $('<td>');
      row1.append(cell2);
      let input3 = $("<input>").attr({"class":"input1"});
      cell2.append(input3);
  });
  cell1.append(button);
  
  
  $("#mainDiv").append(table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="maintest()">
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
```

I want to insert the row before selectedRow but it adds new after this row

**Note :I am using insertBefore method**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you call `insertBefore()`, which works exactly as you require, but then you immediately call `append()` which moves the row to the end of the `table`. To fix your problem simply remove the `append()` call.

That being said, you should note that you can make your code much less verbose by chaining method calls and using `appendTo()` and inline signatures where available. Try this:

```js
function maintest() {
  let $table = $('<table>').prop("id", "testTable");
  let $row0 = $('<tr>').prop("id", "selectedRow").appendTo($table);  
  let $cell0 = $('<td>').appendTo($row0);  
  let $input2 = $("<input>").addClass("input0").appendTo($cell0);
  let $cell1 = $('<td>').appendTo($row0);

  let $button = $("<button>").addClass('btn').text("Button").click(function() {
    let $row1 = $('<tr>').insertBefore($("#selectedRow"));
    let $cell2 = $('<td>').appendTo($row1);
    let input3 = $("<input>").addClass("input1").appendTo($cell2);
  }).appendTo($cell1);

  $("#mainDiv").append($table);
}

maintest();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Note that this could be simplified further by creating the dummy content in the DOM and cloning it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan